# Split string using separator skipping first occurrence

Tags: python, string

I am splitting a string file_path below, so that it returns "abc/def". As you can see, I am splitting by '/' and then joining them back '/'.

```
file_path = 'abc/def/xyz.txt'
path_prefix = "/".join(file_path.split("/")[0:2])
```

Is it possible to split the file_path string by '/' but skipping the first occurrence of '/' ? That way I don't have to perform join.

Comment: I fail to understand why would anyone -1 this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str.rsplit` method with a `maxsplit` of `1` instead:

```
file_path.rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[0]
```

Comment: how about skipping the last occurrence. Meaning "abc/def/xyz.txt" becomes "def/xyz.txt" I didn't find anything on that in the rsplit api.

Comment: For that you can use `file_path.split('/', maxsplit=1)[1]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
>>> 'a/b/c/d'.rsplit('/', 1)
['a/b/c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways you can get path splitting wrong if you are trying to do this in a generalized or portable way. You might consider using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) rather than rolling your own. For example:

```
import os.path
file_path = 'abc/def/xyz.txt'

os.path.dirname(file_path)
# 'abc/def'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know, however for my use case, I am getting a fixed path as input.